# Gatsby project works in development but I have error when deploying it (netlify, zeit)

Tags: node-modules, gatsby, netlify

My gatsby project has this structure:

```
    Project
          node_modules
          plugins
                gatsby-source-cloud       // Local Plugin with code from scratch
                        node_modules
                        gatsby-node.js
                        package.json
                        utis.js
          public
          src
          gatsby-config.js // Here one of the plugins resolve to the local plugin above
          gatsby-node.js
          package.json
```

This code works perfect in the development environment, but when trying to put in production (netlify, zeit) after deploying to github, throw a error:

The gatsby-node.js that is nested in the local plugin (plugins/gatsby-source-cloud/gatsby-node.js) cannot find one module that is in the nested node_modules (pugins/gatsby-source-cloud/node_modules).

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy the Gatsby source code. You must run `gatsby build` and deploy the output of that which will be HTML, CSS and JS.

Have a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-and-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

I already sorted. I forgot to post the solution here.
It is only to compile the nested package.json from the root directory and not from the nested one.
To do that we need to put a property more in scripts:

```
"postinstall": "cd plugins/gatsby-source-cloud && npm i"
```

So, then all package.json (the one in the root and the other in gatsby-source-cloud) are compiled from the root correctly when deploying to the server.